# Sort Multidimensional Vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a two dimensional vector A

```
vector < vector <int> > A;
```

the inner vector is of constant length 3. I want to sort A according to the values of 2nd element in the inner vector. Like we can sort a database table according to any of its column.

How do I do that?

Comment: Just write a comparison function and call `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::sort(std::begin(m), std::end(m),
          [](std::vector<int> const &lhs,
             std::vector<int> const &rhs) { return lhs[1] < rhs[1]; });
```

Be careful though as this is not a stable sort and will not preserve the order of lines that have the same second element. Use `std::stable_sort` if you want this. The usage is identical.